# ValueError when converting string to integer in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace the strings in the `Years` column of the Dataframe below with just the numbers in the string. For example, I would like to change `ZC025YR` to `025`. My code is as follows:

```
import urllib, urllib2
import csv
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile
from pprint import pprint, pformat

my_url = 'http://www.bankofcanada.ca/stats/results/csv'
data = urllib.urlencode({"lookupPage": "lookup_yield_curve.php",
                         "startRange": "1986-01-01",
                         "searchRange": "all"})
request = urllib2.Request(my_url, data)
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
zipdata = result.read()
zipfile = ZipFile(StringIO(zipdata))

df = pd.read_csv(zipfile.open(zipfile.namelist()[0]))

df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Date'])

df.rename(columns={'variable': 'Years'}, inplace=True)
```

The dataframe I currently have looks like this:

```
              Date     Years          value
0       1986-01-01   ZC025YR             na
1       1986-01-02   ZC025YR   0.0948511020
2       1986-01-03   ZC025YR   0.0972953210
3       1986-01-06   ZC025YR   0.0965403640
.....
```

However, if I add the code below in order to restructure my dataframe I get the error `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer` which in the line `df['Years'] = df['Years'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)` which is strange because when I look at the `Year`'s data in the CSV File I don't see there being any 'NaN' associated with it.

```
#Converting the strings in this column into just the number of Years
df['Years'] = df['Years'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)
df['Years'] = df.Years/100
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a new function which will convert strings to `integer` and call that in the `Series.apply` method as follows -

EDIT: Adding logic to default empty strings to `0` , use a different value if you want to handle empty strings in `years` colomn differently

```
import re
def getYear(s):
    x = re.search('(\d+)',s)
    return int(x.groups()[0]) if x is not None else 0 # or however you want to handle it
```

Then use this function as -

```
df['Years'] = df['Years'].apply(getYear)
```

Comment: Thanks. But I get the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'` in the line `df['Years'] = df['Years'].apply(getYear)`

Comment: do a `print(s)` at start of function, check if you have any string that doesn't match your criteria

Comment: It goes from `ZC025YR` through to `ZC3000YR ZC3000YR` and then gives the `AttributError` above. I don't know why this is. Somehow there appear to be `NaN`'s after this I'm guessing, but there aren't any in the CSV File.

Comment: Can you update the question with the end part of the csv file, where you think the issue is ?

Comment: I've been looking at the CSV File and can't gauge where the issue is as I don't see any `NaN`'s associated with the Year's Column. To see what I mean, the csv file is available here [http://www.bankofcanada.ca/stats/results/csv]

Comment: I am not able to access that

Comment: there are empty string in the Years column

Comment: @AnandSKumar Just one further question. Do you know how I could divide the data in the `Years` column by 100? I used your code with the modification `return (int(x.groups()[0]))/100 if x is not None else 0` but that gave `0`'s instead of `0.25`'s in the first few rows of the `Years` Column.

Comment: instead of `int` try converting to `float`